# A polynomial equation with possible trivial solution

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $p(x,y)=p(x_{1}, \dots,x_{n}, y_{1}, \dots, y_{n})$ be a real polynomial over with $2n$ variable. Assume that

1) it is homogeneous with total degree $l>2$ ,

2) for any $x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$
$$
p(y,z)-p(x+y,z)+p(x,y+z)-p(x,y)=0,
$$
3) and $p(0,0)=0$.

How to prove that $p(x,y)=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas. Observe that by putting $x=0$ in the second condition we have $p(0,y+z)=p(y)$ $\forall$ $y,z$. Thus we have $p(0,y)=0$ $\forall$ $y$ Similar argument shows by putting $y=0$ $p(y,0)=$ $\forall$ $y$.

Comment: This implies that $p(x,y)=\sum x_{i}y_{j}q(x,y)$ for some i,j. Do you see a possible attack strategy:)?